# pexpect fails to match command if greater than 65 characters

Tags: python, expect

Issue with [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/doc/), python module.

Pexpect fails to do expected behavior if the length of the command is greater than 65.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pexpect

sshCmd='ssh root@15.186.22.105'
prompt='[root@user ~]#'
ConnectToClient=pexpect.spawn(sshCmd)
ConnectToClient.expect('password')
ConnectToClient.send('abcd')
ConnectToClient.expect(prompt)
ConnectToClient.send('echo abcdefghijklmnopqrst111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 ')
ConnectToClient.expect(prompt) ---> PASS
command = 'echo abcdefghijklmnopqrst111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
ConnectToClient.expect(command, prompt)
```

While expecting ":", the `command (.*) prompt`  ---> *FAILS* if the length of command is greater than 65.

```
expect_str = "%s(.*)%s" % (command, self._default_prompt)
```

Comment: OP has asked same question on the pexpect development page over a month ago on GitHub, but no reply. https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/225

Comment: I'm going to preface this answer by saying it's been a long time since I've had to consider such things but my memory is thinking that **there is a window size associated with your expect script**. If the terminal isn't the same size when you run the script as when you recorded it, there will be issues. I can't seem to find links to support this but I'm 99% sure I found the answer years ago wandering the darkened back alleys of IBM Developerworks.

Comment: @steve He added another [comment there also](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/225#issuecomment-129581609)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things wrong with your program.  The last line is illegal:

```
ConnectToClient.expect(command, prompt)
```

is not valid, as expect takes as 2nd argument a timeout number, not a string.

The other problem is that in the call:

```
ConnectToClient.expect(prompt)
```

`prompt` should be a regex (regular expression). You provide a string, which will be compiled into a regex. However, in a regex the character `[` is special so you need to escape it. Either set

```
prompt = r'\[root@user ~\]#'
```

or instead of using `.expect()` use `.expect_exact()` which wants strings, not regexes.

Answer (score 0):

By default pexpect windowsize is set to (24 rows and 80 coloumns) 
in my case, when length of prompt and command exceeds 80 . I face this issue.
By changing the setwinsize(24,80) to setwinsize(24,150), It works fine.